# Computing an Integral Using Complex Analysis

Tags: complex-analysis

Does anyone know how to compute

$$
\int^{2\pi}_{0} \frac{1}{3 + \cos\theta} \, d\theta
$$

using tools from complex analysis? I'm not sure how to get started, or if complex analysis is even needed to do this.

Comment: It's not required, but it is a standard exercise in a complex analysis course to do it with residues.

Comment: I have done very similar computation [here.](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/463763/compute-complex-integral/464743#464743)

Answer (score 3):

Recall that $\cos\theta = (e^{i\theta}+e^{-i\theta})/2$, and change variables to $z=e^{i\theta}$.  Then you are integrating around a circle, and can look for poles.

Comment: Why was this downvoted?

Answer (score 2):

Let $z=e^{i \theta}$ and $\alpha = 3 -2\sqrt{2}$.  Then the integrand is $$ \frac{1}{3+\frac{z+z^{-1}}{2}} = \frac{2z}{z^2+6z+1} = \frac{2z}{(z+\alpha)(z+\alpha^{-1})} =\frac{\sqrt{2}}{4}\left( \frac{1}{1+\alpha z}-\frac{\alpha z^{-1}}{1+\alpha z^{-1}}\right).$$  And since $0<\alpha<1$ and $|z|=1$ this can be expanded as a geometric series  $$\frac{\sqrt{2}}{4}\left(1 +\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}(-\alpha)^k(z^k+z^{-k}) \right) = \frac{\sqrt{2}}{4} + \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2} \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}(-\alpha)^k \cos(k \theta).$$  The integral over $[0, 2\pi]$ of all terms except the constant term equals $0$ and therefore $$\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{1}{3+\cos(\theta)}d\theta = \frac{\pi \sqrt{2}}{2}.$$

Answer (score 0):

If complex analysis is not considered as necessary, you could use the tangent half-angle substitution and then arrive to Pi / Sqrt[2]. The antiderivative is 
ArcTan[Tan[theta/2] / Sqrt[2]] / Sqrt[2]

Answer (score 0):

Direct computation using identity:

$$ \cos x = \frac{1-\tan^2(x/2)}{1 + \tan^2(x/2)}.$$

Let
$$ f(\theta) =\frac{1}{3+\cos\theta} =\frac{1+ \tan^2{(\theta/2)}}{4 +2\tan^2{(\theta/2)}} = \frac{1}{2 +\tan^2{(\theta/2)}} \frac{d}{d\theta}\left(\tan\frac{\theta}{2}\right) = \frac{du}{2+u^2},$$

where $u = \tan(\theta/2).$ Thus,
$$ \int f(\theta) d\theta = \frac{1}{\sqrt2} \arctan \left(\frac{u}{\sqrt2}\right).$$

Coming back to the original integral:

$$\begin{align}
I &= \int_0^{2\pi} f(\theta) d\theta\\
& = \int_0^\pi f(\theta) d\theta + \int_\pi^{2\pi} f(\theta) d\theta \\
& = \int_0^{\infty} \frac{du}{2+u^2} +
 \int_0^{\infty} \frac{du}{2+u^2} \\
&=  \frac{2}{\sqrt2} \arctan \left(\frac{u}{\sqrt2}\right)\bigg|_0^\infty \\
&=\frac{\pi\sqrt2}{2}.
\end{align}$$

Answer (score -1):

Let $\cos \theta = \dfrac{z^2+1}{2z}$, $\,d\theta=\dfrac{dz}{iz}$.

Comment: Why was this down voted?